# How to make gravity in Blitz3D?

Tags: software-engineering, blitzmax

I am making a game in Blitz3d and I made simple gravity, however once the object falls on the ground, it goes through it very slowly. The ground is a plane and I have collision on it.

This is a pretty old engine, and not a lot of people are using it but I decided to use it because it's easier than Unity3D for me and it's very basic and customizable.

Here's my code:

```
AppTitle "FPS"
Graphics3D 800,600,32,2
SetBuffer BackBuffer()
SeedRnd MilliSecs()
HidePointer


;Objects
Global player = CreatePivot()
Global camera = CreateCamera(player)
Global cube = CreateCube()
Global light = CreateLight()
Global plane = CreatePlane()
Global cube2 = CreateCube(player)
col_plane = 1
col_player = 2
col_cube = 3

;Vars
gravity# = -.00001
plx# = 0
ply# = 0
plz# = 0
pldx# = 0
pldy# = 0
pldz# = 0

;Textures
CameraClsColor camera,135,206,250
box = LoadTexture("models\box.png")
dirt = LoadTexture("models\dirt.jpg")

;Object Details
EntityType cube,col_cube
EntityType player,col_player
EntityType plane,col_plane
EntityRadius player,1.2
EntityRadius plane,1

PositionEntity player,0,10,5
PositionEntity cube,0,1,5
PositionEntity light,0,2,0
PositionEntity plane,0,0,0
EntityTexture cube,box
EntityTexture plane,dirt
ScaleTexture dirt,5,5
CameraRange camera,0.25,200

;Called Functions
While Not KeyHit(1)
    Cls
    ;Collisions
    Collisions col_player,col_plane,2,2
    Collisions col_player,col_cube,2,2

    If ply < -2 Then
        ply = 0
        pldy = -pldy*.39
    EndIf
    If ply < -1.8 Then
        pldx = .6*pldx
        pldz = .6*pldz
        If KeyDown(57) Then pldy = 2
    EndIf
    pldy = pldy + gravity
    plx = plx + pldx
    ply = ply + pldy
    plz = plz + pldz
    PositionEntity player,EntityX(player)+plx,EntityY(player)+ply,EntityZ(player)+plz

    control()
    RenderWorld()
    UpdateWorld()
    MoveMouse GraphicsWidth()/2, GraphicsHeight()/2
    Flip
Wend

End

;Functions
Function control()
    If KeyDown(42) ;Shift (for running)
        If KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(30) ;W and A
            MoveEntity player,-0.15,0,0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(32) ;W and D
            MoveEntity player,0.15,0,0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(30) ;S and A
            MoveEntity player,-0.15,0,-0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(32) ;S and D
            MoveEntity player,0.15,0,-0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) ;W
            MoveEntity player,0,0,0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(31) ;S
            MoveEntity player,0,0,-0.15
        ElseIf KeyDown(30) ;A
            MoveEntity player,-0.15,0,0
        ElseIf KeyDown(32) ;D
            MoveEntity player,0.15,0,0
        End If
    Else ;Walking
        If KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(30) ;W and A
            MoveEntity player,-0.1,0,0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(32) ;W and D
            MoveEntity player,0.1,0,0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(30) ;S and A
            MoveEntity player,-0.1,0,-0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) And KeyDown(32) ;S and D
            MoveEntity player,0.1,0,-0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(17) ;W
            MoveEntity player,0,0,0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(31) ;S
            MoveEntity player,0,0,-0.1
        ElseIf KeyDown(30) ;A
            MoveEntity player,-0.1,0,0
        ElseIf KeyDown(32) ;D
            MoveEntity player,0.1,0,0
        End If
    End If

    While KeyDown(16) ;Q
        RotateEntity camera,MouseXSpeed(),10,10
    Wend
    While KeyDown(18) ;E
        RotateEntity camera,0,-10,-10
    Wend

    TurnEntity player, 0, -MouseXSpeed()/6.0, 0
    TurnEntity camera, MouseYSpeed()/6.0, 0, 0
    If EntityPitch(camera) < -70
        RotateEntity camera, -70, EntityYaw(camera), EntityRoll(camera)
    ElseIf EntityPitch(camera) > 70
        RotateEntity camera, 70, EntityYaw(camera), EntityRoll(camera)
    EndIf
End Function
```

If there's some one who can actually help me with this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @jhocking I just started using Blitz3D. I thought that I fell through the plane BECAUSE I didn't have a collision with it, so I am gonna fix it right now. I am also going to fix the collisions and tell you if it worked or not.

Comment: It's not really clear what about jhocking's comment worked for you. Can you post your own answer with details about how you got this to work, and what the problem was?

Comment: @Byte56 I did sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Blitz3D, blast from the past!)

It's been so long so a bunch of things I'm wondering about (these may or may not be relevant to your question): Why are you setting a collision radius for the plane? Why are you calling 'Collisions' every frame, rather than once when declaring the collision types? Shouldn't UpdateWorld() be before RenderWorld()?

All three of these things are related to collision detection, and are oddities I spotted in your code:

1) The plane shouldn't have a collision radius defined, since it will be used for polygon collisions and not sphere collisions.

2) The 'Collisions' command sets the relationship between various collision types, so it only needs to be set once to say "this type of object collides with that type of object"

3) Collision detection is actually applied during UpdateWorld(), so you would want the simulation to resolve collisions before drawing the frame.

Comment: This might be the hint that lead to a solution, but I don't think it's an answer on its own.

Comment: yeah this was a comment at first, but he asked for it as an answer after I helped him. and I was wondering which part actually solved the problem, but it looks like he did all three things

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my own answer saying exactly *what I did*.

First off, I moved

```
Collisions col_player,col_cube,2,2
Collisions col_player,col_plane,2,2
```

out of the `While Not KeyHit(1)` loop, as that might have conflicted with my current gravity code.
Second off, I removed `EntityRadius plane,1`, and thirdly I put `UpdateWorld()` before `RenderWorld()`, and everything works just as expected now! Big thanks to **@jhocking**!

Answer (score 0):

so this is pretty easy... collision detection is the best method- once you have the collisions between terrain or plane  and your player entity then do this...

your code:

```
ElseIf KeyDown(30) ;
MoveEntity player,-0.1,0,0
```

change to:

```
ElseIf KeyDown(30) ;
MoveEntity player,-0.1,-0.1,0
```

This way there will be a downward Y force on the player- this will make it more difficult to climb rising terrain and also provide for a falling motion.